# Small matrices won't appear on the same line in LaTeX

Tags: latex, matrix

I have a product of two matrices that I would like to appear next to each other on the same line.  Even though I have shrunk them down to allow room, LaTeX automatically sends the second matrix to the next line so that they don't appear as a product.  What's the word on the street?  Thanks.

Comment: There are various reasons thing like this happen.  Can you post a latex snippit?

Answer (score 2):

Word on the street is that what you're trying to do should work just fine. I tried both

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

and

```
    $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
```

and in both cases the matrices appeared on the same line. If that doesn't do it for you, post a code sample...

Answer (score 1):

What you should probably really do is do them in displaymath; big things inline look ugly.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a line break in MATRICES, use `\hbox{MATRICES}' .

Answer (score 1):

```
$\begin{bmatrix}54 & 77 & 6F & 20\\ 4F & 6E & 65 & 20\\ 4E & 69 & 6E & 65\\ 20 & 54 & 77 & 6F\\ \end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}54 & 68 & 61 & 74\\ 73 & 20 & 6D & 79\\20 & 4B & 75 & 6E\\67 & 20 & 46 & 75\end{bmatrix}$ This matrix multiplication works well.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this probably happened was because you were having 2 different equation environments. Equation environments " `\[ \]` " will push the matrices on different lines.